# Django how to pupulate database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some problem to populate my database.   I tried to stick to the Django  Tutorial  but it doesn't work.  I miss something but i don't know what :(.

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class  QA_machine_DB(models.Model):
    QAmachine = models.CharField( max_length = 64)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.QAmachine, self.status)

class Report(models.Model):

     store = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
     service = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
     user = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
     dump_date = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
     branch= models.CharField(max_length= 128)

     FK_report=models.ForeignKey(QA_machine_DB, null=True, blank=True,   on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

     def __str__(self):
         return "%s %s" % (self.store, self.user)
```

The following  code is to to populate the DB:

```
def import_data_django(self):
# import Data to Django

    remote_data= self.report.to_dict('index')
    current_machine = QA_machine_DB.objects.get_or_create( QAmachine =self.name,
                                         status = self.status,)

    for key in remote_data.keys():
        Report.objects.get_or_create(service= remote_data[key]['service_name'],
                                             user=remote_data[key]['user'],
                                             store= remote_data[key]['shop'],
                                             dump_date=remote_data[key]['date'],
                                             branch = remote_data[key]['issues_key'],
                                            FK_report= current_machine) # I guess here is the problem


    print ( self.name, '-',self.status, 'in DB :)'  )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    machines=['qa0668']
    #machines=['qa0668','con-qa-1010','qa1313']
    for elt in machines :
        machine=QA_machine_(elt)
        machine.fill_info_status()
        machine.find_state_QA_nmachine()
        machine.import_data_django()
```

I got the error :

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QA_machine_DB'
IF someone has a clue what I miss please... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

```
current_machine = QA_machine_DB.objects.get_or_create( QAmachine =self.name,
                                     status = self.status,)
```

get_or_create returns a tuple (instance, created). Try this

```
current_machine, _ = QA_machine_DB.objects.get_or_create( QAmachine =self.name,
                                     status = self.status,)
```